# joining the similarities in a database

Tags: sql-server, join

I've got 2 table which have file paths in then.

```
the first table has 2 column:
P_ID
Path-Snip

the second table also has 2 column:
Path_def
Value
```

The Path_Snip is a reduced path which is related to an area of the program.

What I'd like to do is Join the two table to have a table with 4 column:

```
P_ID
Path_Snip
Path_def
Value
```

I'd like to match the paths together so that the similar Path_Snips are joined with the similar Path_def:

Example of what I'd like the table to look like:

> P_ID   = 1
>
> Path_Snip  = branches/Projects/Enhancements2015Q1/Encryption
>
> Path_def   = branches/Projects/Enhancements2015Q1/Encryption/Encryption.csproj
>
> Value      =  12

As the 2 paths match I'd like to keep them together

Comment: Will `Path_Snip` always be a shortened version of `Path_def` ?

Comment: Path_Snip is a shortened version of a Path_def but they will be different there are 55 different Path_def and I'm trying to find which Path_snip they best match to

Comment: Will you always have records both sides? or can you have Project definition entries without `snip` entries?

Comment: @FraserMunro What does "best" mean? If our Path_Snip is `branches/Projects/Enhancements`, then which is the best match from the following? `branches/Projects/Enhancements2015Q1/` or `branches/Projects/Enhancements2015Q1/Encryption/Encryption.csproj` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a `JOIN` with `LIKE`:

```
SELECT
    t1.p_ID
    , t1.Path_snip
    , t2.Path_def
    , t2.Value
FROM table1 t1
   INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.Path_def LIKE '%' + t1.Path_Snip + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `like` operator in `join`:

```
select * from t1
join t2 on t1.Path-Snip like t2.Path_def + '%' or t2.Path_def like t1.Path-Snip + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment...

```
SELECT
    s.p_ID
    , s.Path-snip
    , d.Path_def
    , d.Value
FROM tblDef d
   LEFT JOIN tblSnip s ON d.Path_def LIKE s.Path-Snip + '%'
```

I have used `LEFT join` here in case you have entries in the `Def` table with nothing in the snip table.

Comment: With non-matching you mean. You might have corresponding entries in the `Def` table, but your rule might not pick them up.

Comment: I have asked the question above, I'm making an assumption that you may always have an entry in the `Def` table but nothing in `Snip` table, unless something is added in the `C# Project` file _.csproj_

Answer (score 0):

Radu's question on 'best match' in the comments is a valid one. But, assuming a simple scenario, of the left portion of the paths matching, and assuming left,right joins are not required and inner joins will work (both tables will have uniquely matching records al the time), here is a different version, using `SubString` :

```
Select T1.*, T2.* From Table1 T1, Table2 T2 Where 
Substring(T2.Path_def, 1, Len(T1.Path_snip)) = T1.Path_snip
```